# Strange response after http POST with JSON in Java

Tags: java, android, json, http

I'm doing what should be a simple http post that includes a json string as the http body.

?[image]

All looks good except the response itself - when I turn it into a String it comes back looking strange (not text). How might I get this in plain text? Or what did I do wrong during the post to get this response? (note - if I exclude the cookies during the POST I do get plain html back from the server w/ a valid "access denied" message)

Full code for this solution is below

```
public class BaseHttpService {
    public ResponseAndCookies doHttpPostWithUrlWithJson(String url, String key, CookieStore cookies) {
        try {
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity("{\"filters\":true}");
            se.setContentType("text/xml");
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpost.setEntity(se);

            httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            return executeHttpRequest(httpost, cookies);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public ResponseAndCookies executeHttpRequest(HttpRequestBase http, CookieStore cookieStore) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String result = "";

        if (cookieStore != null) {
            ((DefaultHttpClient) httpclient).setCookieStore(cookieStore);
        }

        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(http);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                result = convertStreamToString(instream);
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Cookie> cookies = ((DefaultHttpClient) httpclient).getCookieStore().getCookies();
        CookieStore postCookieStore = ((DefaultHttpClient) httpclient).getCookieStore();

        ResponseAndCookies x = new ResponseAndCookies();
        x.setCookies(cookies);
        x.setResponse(result);
        x.setCookieStore(postCookieStore);

        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

        return x;
    }

    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is mainly a guess, but it might fix the situation if you set encoding for [InputStreamReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) manually. I don't know exact value to do this but I would give UTF-8 a go first.

Comment: being explicit w/UTF-8 didn't seem to change the result

Answer (score 0):

You tried to read an UTF-8 String with the platform encoding it seems.
Find out the Content encoding for the returned response and use that to convert to a string.

Let me know if you want to replace the code above with 2 lines of code. I got a project for you that already takes care of cookies and converting content.

Comment: always up for 2 lines of code over this boiler plate - hook me up :) (also if I use httpfox to find the returned response and it shows the resp type as "application/json" how would I get this out correctly(as string) thank you!

Comment: `Resty r = new Resty(); r.json(url, content(new JSONObject("{\"filters\":\"true\"}));` I'm assuming the return object is json here. There is a Resty branch for Android at https://github.com/mravenel/Resty

Comment: The original API is at http://beders.github.com/Resty/Resty/Overview.html  (DISCLAIMER: I'm the author) It should also support cookies automatically

Comment: excellent mention - I'll looking into how I can modify http headers/cookies/etc

Comment: any special needs? headers should be set up correctly for you. Cookies are stored automatically and re-transmitted. Also, the resulting AbstractResource (JSONResource in this examples) has a getUrlConnection which is the standard Java UrlConnection (which you can cast to HttpUrlConnection to access headers and stuff)

Comment: if you really need to add additional headers (apart from Content type, User Agent, etc.) override addStandardHeaders(...) in Resty

Comment: yeah I need to modify a few special headers so it looks like the override you mentioned will be my best option.

Comment: I'll add this request to my TODO list. Thx for the feedback!